# Configuring Google Domains/Domain Forwardings

Tags: google, domains

A complete webmaster noob here, and I'm sorry for the noobish question. I recently purchased a domain through Google Domains. I've also setup a personal Apache web server running off a non-standard port (ISP blocks 80), currently serving a default template wordpress site.

It is currently setup:

IP.ADDRESS:PORT

```
12.13.14.15:1111
```

Yields my site, on or off the local network. However, I would like to be able to simply type "www.mydomain.com" and have it yield the same page. I bought my domain through Google Domains and I have no clue on how to set this up.

I've tried working the problem out by applying the rules as seen in this link, under [the SRV subheading](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251147).

```
_http._tcp SRV 1h 10 5 PORT(ex. 1111) www.mydomain.com. 

www A 1h SERVER_IPADDRESS
```

How I understand the first rule:

Service http, protocol tcp, type SRV, 1h timeout, priority, weight, the port on my machine the request should be funneled through, and the domain

How I understand the second rule:

subdomain, type A, 1h timeout, my servers ip address

And so in my mind, I image these rules working like this:

1. Browser makes request for "www.mydomain.com"
2. Google Nameserver applies those rules,
3. My system recieves the request on port 1111, forwards that to port 80 of the server, and then feeds the browser the requested page

Applying these rules does not work (It tries to log me into my router instead of serving the landing page). Can anyone help me figure this out?

Side note: This isn't a website for others, just me learning and playing around. I know it's insecure, and I don't plan on having it up except for my playing around. I'm not very experienced so I don't know the ways in which it is vulnerable, however. If someone could tell/link me the risks of this setup, I'd love to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: Use port forwarding in your router - assuming you have a router with your DSL or cable. For what it is worth, putting a web server on an odd port may still get you into trouble with your ISP. It may be just a matter of time. You may want to chose another ISP.

Comment: @closetnoc I have set the port (ex. 1111) to forward to 80 on my server. The request of (www.mydomain.com) does not send a request through that port

Comment: If you have a router that is where you want to do the forward.

Comment: @closetnoc I have, Im not sure if the DNS is sending the request to that forwarded port, but port 80 instead

Comment: DNS does not deal with ports. It only ties an IP address to a domain name and defines a few records for e-mail and the like. That is it. Any request from a browser would be HTTP of HTTPS. The browser sets the port to 80 for HTTP when it builds the request packet. You can use a domain name with a port of course like example.com:1111, however, if that is not what you want, you will have to set up port forwarding on the device that bridges the WAN to the LAN and that is likely your router assuming you have one . Otherwise, the request will never get to you computer.

Comment: @closetnoc Can you explain that SRV rule example I had? What is the purpose of specifying a port there?

Comment: I do not know SRV. However, your assumption is that your request packet would arrive to your computer. I am trying to gently suggest to you that is not likely the case and that any request packet will be stopped at your router and hence where you need to solve the problem. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

SRV records are not designed to work with HTTP.   No browsers support them.

From [Why do browsers not use SRV records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063378/why-do-browsers-not-use-srv-records) by [Teddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54435/teddy):

> The RFC for SRV records specifies that it may *not* be used by pre-existing protocols which did not already specify the use of SRV records in their specifications.  I.e. no SRV in the HTTP spec - browsers are, by the SRV standard, prohibited from using it.
>
> This does not prohibit a new HTTP 1.2 standard from specifying the use of SRV records, though.  However, Mark Andrews [proposed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2007AprJun/0011.html) this in April 2007 to the IETF HTTP working group, but got no response.

Comment: 2018 update: SRV ports are [not supported in HTTP/2 either](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8404612).

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is impossible, and SRV records cannot help you.

Port 80 is the default for HTTP traffic, so if your ISP blocks port 80, that means that `www.example.com` will be blocked because under the hood it's actually `www.example.com:80`.

The only alternatives are to:

1. Be okay with needing to type in `www.example.com:1111` or other port.

or

2. Use a reverse-proxy.

---

See related: [Can DNS point to specific port?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55123/can-dns-point-to-specific-port)