# How to point my domain to a my server's IP address and configure it to show my website?

Tags: domains, url, dns, apache, ip-address

I'm doing website on the Linux server (still learning) And I have on 1 IP address to host many web sites.  I will have them separately.  For example 104.000.0.000:203 for one website and 104.000.0.000:204 for another website.

I know that I need to configure the Linux server to use the folder containing the WordPress files.  I also know I need to put this IP into  GoDaddy as a DNS `A` record. I don't know the Linux commands and where I they should go.  All I remember is something with `site-enabled apache2` and nothing else.

Comment: Are 203 and 204 port numbers on your example IP addresses?  If so you can't point DNS to a specific port number.   See [Can DNS point to specific port?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55123/can-dns-point-to-specific-port)

Comment: And also do not use ports below 1024 for such kind of hosting. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6335#section-6 TL;DR use ports in range 1024-49151