# Forward domain to a specific port and IP while using the forwarded domain in the URL

Tags: url, domain-forwarding

I have 2 domains. One is hosted with google domains and the other with Namecheap. I don't really care which one I use as the primary or if I even end up using 2 for my purposes.

I would like to be able to do `sub.domain.example` and have it hit a IP using a certain port. Google domains will let me do this from 1 domain to another but it shows the hand off. So I go to `sub.domain.example` and it shows my redirect in the address bar as `domain2.example:1234`.

I want it to just stay in the address bar as `sub.domain.example` but hit my IP using the specific port and do a different port for a different sub.

I have an SSL cert rolling on 1 domain and google will make one on the other one easily.

I think I need a SRV record but I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: See also [Can DNS point to specific port?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55123/can-dns-point-to-specific-port)  (TL;DR: No, it can't for websites)

Comment: "Domain forwarding" means redirecting to or framing some other domain.   I think you are actually looking to use the domain name for the site.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do what you are asking [ for HTTP/HTTPS ] - Unfortunately - and I wish this were not the case, the protocol does not recognize SRV records or any equivalent structure.

Possible workaround -

- Run a reverse proxy on sub.domain.com to pick up data off domain.2.com:1234 (this will push all the traffic through the subdomain proxy though).  If, for example, you are running a service on port 1234 on an Apache webserver you can configure Apache with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse rules to do this.